# How to trigger only the profiler on Xdebug with no config change

Tags: xdebug, php-8, xdebug-3

Xdebug is working with my containers. I can use the debugger to step through the code.

I have the following settings in xdebug.ini:

```ini
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.discover_client_host=0
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.output_dir=/app
```

When I want to trigger Xdebug when I'm hitting an endpoint I just add:

```
?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM
```

in the CLI I do:

```bash
export XDEBUG_TRIGGER=1
```

and then call the a script.

Now my question is how can I trigger the profiler without changing anything in the xdebug.ini.
Just have a one off session where the profiler produces a cachegrind file.
I've tried adding `XDEBUG_TRIGGER=profile` to the query string but with no result.

Note, I understand that I can go to the ini add `profile` to `xdebug.mode=develop,debug,profile` (adding profile to the list), restart the container and then that will produce the cachegrind.

What I'm really asking is how can I do this via some environment variable with the need to change any setting or restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

From [xdebug configuration](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug):

> You can also set Xdebug's mode by setting the XDEBUG_MODE environment
> variable on the command-line; this will take precedence over the
> xdebug.mode setting, but will not change the value of the xdebug.mode
> setting.